# Populating a form dynamically based on user input in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, dynamic, http-post

My question is similar to Engram's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223149/how-do-you-handle-the-output-of-a-dynamically-generated-form-in-aspnet-mvc), but my question goes a bit further.  The way i intend it to work is I have a textbox asking how many entries a user is going to make.  After they input the number, I need to create that many more textboxes to allow for entries (and then repeat the same process with those textboxes, but baby steps first...)  I tried collecting the keys on the post, but it only returns the initial textbox asking for the number of entries.  I'm still trying to get a grasp on MVC and the tutorials/videos so far don't delve this deep into it yet.  Then again, I know this is probably something I could handle using JQuery, but I'd still be stuck in the same situation.

This is the controller I'm using:

```
[AcceptVerbsAttribute("POST")]
    public ActionResult Create(int tbxNumberOfExercises)
    {
        ViewData["number"] = tbxNumberOfExercises;
        foreach (var key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            string keyString = key.ToString();
            if (keyString.StartsWith("tbox_exercise", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                string recNum = keyString.Substring(13, keyString.Length - 13);
                string approvedKey = Request.Form["tbox_exercise" + recNum];
                int number;
                int.TryParse(approvedKey, out number);
            }
        }
        return View("Create");
    }
```

And this is my aspx:

```
<form action="/CreateWorkout/Create" method="post">
Number of Exercises:
<%= Html.TextBox("tbxNumberOfExercises") %>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Set Exercise Number" />
</form>
<% if (ViewData["number"] != null)%>
There are this many:<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["number"])%>
<br />
and this line should show up
<% if (ViewData["number"] != null)
   {
       int max = (int)ViewData["number"];

       for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
       {%>
          <br />
          <br />
          <%= Html.TextBox("tbox_exercise" + i) %>
    <% }
   } %>
<% if (ViewData["s"] != null) %>
<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["s"]) %>
```

Is there something I'm overlooking, not comprehending, or should I quit while I'm at it because it seems like I'll never get it?

Thanks in advance for any help -- I'm just trying to learn as most I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd break this up in stages, you'll need to add a "Save" view someplace depending on what you want.

Scott

```
<form action="/Demo01/Create" method="post">
Number of Exercises:
<%= Html.TextBox("tbxNumberOfExercises") %>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Set Exercise Number" />
</form>
<% if (ViewData["number"] != null) {%>
<form action="/Demo01/Save" method="post">
There are this many:<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["number"])%>
<br />
and this line should show up
<% if (ViewData["number"] != null) {
       int max = (int)ViewData["number"];

       for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {%>
<br />
<br />
<%= Html.TextBox("tbox_exercise" + i) %>
<% }
   } %>
<% if (ViewData["s"] != null) %>
<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["s"]) %>
<input type="submit" value="Save Exercises" />
<% } %>
</form>
```

And then in your controller something like this:

```
public class Demo01Controller : Controller {
    public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbsAttribute("POST")]
    public ActionResult Create(int tbxNumberOfExercises) {
        ViewData["number"] = tbxNumberOfExercises;
        return View("Create");
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Save() {
        foreach (var key in Request.Form.Keys) {
            string keyString = key.ToString();
            if (keyString.StartsWith("tbox_exercise", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                string recNum = keyString.Substring(13, keyString.Length - 13);
                string approvedKey = Request.Form["tbox_exercise" + recNum];
                int number;
                int.TryParse(approvedKey, out number);
            }
        }
        return View(); // return/redirect to wherever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider adding the textboxes client-side via javascript rather than posting back to the server to have the form redrawn, assuming that you can live with javascript as a requirement for using the application.  If not, then @Scott's approach should work.  As a matter of preference I would probably have the Save method take a FormCollection parameter rather than deal with the Request object directly.

The javascript solution would be to have a single textbox and a button to add another.  The user could continue to add textboxes until they have enough.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `</form>` ending tag needs to come at the end of your view.

Try this modified view:

```
<form action="/CreateWorkout/Create" method="post">
Number of Exercises:
<%= Html.TextBox("tbxNumberOfExercises") %>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Set Exercise Number" />
<% if (ViewData["number"] != null)%>
There are this many:<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["number"])%>
<br />
and this line should show up
<% if (ViewData["number"] != null)
   {
       int max = (int)ViewData["number"];

       for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
       {%>
          <br />
          <br />
          <%= Html.TextBox("tbox_exercise" + i) %>
    <% }
   } %>
<% if (ViewData["s"] != null) %>
<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["s"]) %>
</form>
```

I would recommend Scott's approach as far as best practice.  This answer is about getting your exact scenario working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.  I realized at 5 this morning that my issue is that the form didn't include the new textboxes / I needed another form.  I'll have to seriously look into Javascript and actually modifying the DOM as it would be better to keep it client side.

Thanks so much.