# how to dynamically add textbox in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

how to dynamically add and remove textbox in asp.net mvc

Comment: Please be more specific. Give examples of your markup.

Comment: I have an employee registration form and in which user can have multiple qualifications so i want that user can add multiple textboxes and then add their qualification in that textboxes

Comment: Do you want it to happen on the clientside or on the serverside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
$('<input type="text" name="myTextBox" />').appendTo(document.body);
```

The [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method accepts quite a lot of things - dom elements, other jQuery objects, selectors. You may also want to check the other [DOM manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer.. I haven't done this, but.

I would look at these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300957/populating-a-form-dynamically-based-on-user-input-in-asp-net-mvc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223149/how-do-you-handle-the-output-of-a-dynamically-generated-form-in-aspnet-mvc)