# How should my model be to store data in database from dynamically added textboxes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

My model:

```
public class Order
{
     public int OrderId { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
     public double Width { get; set; }
     public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

In my strongly-typed view for that model I have a form with `TextBoxFor` for that properties like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="AddTextBox()">+</a></td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Width)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Height)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The link with the `AddTextBox()` is a jQuery function to dynamically add another table like that containing more than three textboxes.

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    context.Order.Add(order);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

When debugging I can see that the order object is filled with the data from the form but only with the first quantity, weight and height textbox's values, I know that is the expected behavior and I know I'm receiving all values because I tested like the example below and my Lists got filled correctly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOrder(List<int> Quantity, List<int> Width, List<int> Height)
{
    return View();
}
```

So here is the question again: how should I create a model to hold that array of data and save on my database?

I hope I was clear with the question and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Try public List<Order> Orders {get; set;} in your view model.

Comment: I didn't understand, do you mean adding a List of Orders inside my Orders Model?

Comment: not exactly.  Use a view model, not your domain model, to bind the input.  Have a list of order objects in the view model.  Then in the controller you can iterate through the list and create/populate/edit one individual order object in each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view model has to have a list that you are going to add to. You cannot add models to fixed instance of singletone (which the `@model` is inside your view). SO your model has to be extendable.

Here is your sample, [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

Look what they've done and do the same for your control and view. I built my app completely based on this article - its simple enough to understand for even newbie (with basic knowledge) and implement similar functionality within your realm.
They also have full demo source code you can download and play with

Its just too long to describe the process, in simple words you

1. create dedicated action in your controller and call it using ajax to generate whatever you want to add to your view (`textbox` in your case, but it can certainly be something much more complex) and
2. `$(<your selector>).append(<your result from ajax call>)`.
3. On posting back to controller you get the list with **actual** number of items that you added/removed in your view
4. One by one you add them to your DTO and commit the transaction when you done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have passed on that questions already and found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223149/how-do-you-handle-the-output-of-a-dynamically-generated-form-in-asp-net-mvc) but it isn't what I'm looking for..

Comment: I understood what is in that examples, but let's suppose that I have a Person model that is referenced to the Gift model and when adding a person I want to add as many gifts as I want, how should I do that? That is what I was trying to ask, I my case I need to have many Quantity, Weight and Height with the same OrderId, is that possible?

Comment: definitely is possible. I understood your question. I would do it this way: 1 view for person with his gifts that is variable number of them. Once you postback you know what person it was by its Id, that was originally setup by get action with the same name (keep it in `@HiddenFor` place).
Please let me know if you have any issues implementing this (based on that article your person is fixed, your variable is gifts).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally !

I don't know if I was very clear on my question but here is the solution I found, I don't know if that is very simple or not because I'm not very experienced with programming, so thanks to who tried to help me.

Istead of having only one model I had to create another on to hold on my database all the Measures that every order has, so I changed my model to look like this:

```
public class Order
{
     public int OrderId { get; set; }
     public virtual List<Measures> Measures { get; set;}
     // I have many other properties here but i erased for simplicity...
}

public class Measures
{
     public int MeasuresId { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
     public double Width { get; set; }
     public double Height { get; set; }
     public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

So on my view after adding some `<input>` dinamically all their name attribute was Quantity, Width or Height and the response I was receiving on my controller was like this:

```
Quantity: 10
Width: 20
Height: 16
Quantity: 3
Width: 14
Height: 10
Quantity: 500
Width: 2
Height: 5
```

Finally, my controller is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveOrder(Order Order, List<int> Quantity, List<double> Width, List<double> Height)
    {
        List<Measures> Measures = new List<Measures>();

        //At this point my Order model is filled with all the properties
        //that came from the form and I'll save it to the Database so that
        //this model can have its Id filled from the identity column
        unitOfWork.ServicosRepository.Insert(Order);
        unitOfWork.Save();

        //Now that I have the OrderId I can add how much Measures I want referencing
        //that OrderId to access that further on my View
        for (int i = 0; i < Quantity.Count; i++)
        {
            Measures measures = new Measures { Quantity = Quantity[i], Width = Width[i], Height = Height[i], Order = Order };
            unitOfWork.MedidasRepository.Inserir(medidas);
            unitOfWork.Salva();
            Medidas.Add(medidas);
        }

        return PartialView("_Emitir", Pedido);
    }
```